# Can't use Intel Quicksync(headless) for transcoding

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, encoding, transcoding

/dev/dri and /usr/lib/dri doesn't exist.

vainfo returns:

```
error: can't connect to X server!
error: failed to initialize display
Aborted
```

lspci | grep VGA returns:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

va-driver-all and xserver-xorg-video-intel are already installed.

My kernel: 4.14.14-xanmod19

cat /proc/cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x1c
cpu MHz         : 2130.591
cache size      : 8192 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb retpoline tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips        : 6800.02
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

I'm trying to use Intel Quicksync with Plex to use HW transcoding.

Here's the error from the Plex log, if it helps:

```
Jan 21, 2018 20:44:22.915 [0x7f30e0bff700] ERROR - [FFMPEG] - No VA display found for device: /dev/dri/renderD128.
Jan 21, 2018 20:44:22.915 [0x7f30e0bff700] DEBUG - Codecs: hardware transcoding: opening hw device failed - probably not supported by this system, error: Invalid argument
Jan 21, 2018 20:44:22.915 [0x7f30e0bff700] DEBUG - Scaled up video bitrate to 18057Kbps based on 1.500000x fudge factor.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I get it working? Like I said in the OP, vainfo is broken and Plex can't use it.

Comment: What distro/drivers are you using and where did you install Plex from?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and va-driver-all. Plex is installed with the .deb file provided by Plex.